# Mount Azure File Share on Windows causes File Explorer to hang

Tags: azure

I can mount my Azure File Share successfully using a mapped drive on Windows 10. Everything is fine immediately after mapping the drive.  Later, when launching FileExplorer again, it hangs and can't show the entire navigation pane.  After rebooting the same problem occurs.
I finally gave up mapping the Azure File Share since I have to reboot and disconnect the mapped drive (and usually reboot again) to get File Explorer back to normal.  Does anyone know what causes this problem?

Comment: I gave up.  I can use C# code to read/update all file shares.  I can use Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer with no problems.  Later today, I will turn off my firewall and see what happens when I map the drive.  I have actually found Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to be a tolerable work-around for my scenario.  There are situations where it would be nice to have a mapped drive, but I just live without it for now.

Comment: I did not turn off firewall.  I mapped the Azure file share to windows drive T.  Everything was good (no hanging in Windows Exporer); then I rebooted.  The first launch of Windows File Explorer was good. The second launch has me hung again with Quick access bar running and running; no navigation items appear on the left portion of Windows File Explorer.  I am just lucky I don't really need a mapped drive.  I had an application a few years ago where a mapped drive was crucial and it worked great (it used cloud storage from another company).  I hope Microsoft can fix the problem.

Comment: Disconnecting the troublesome mapped drive is even more frustrating.  I launch Windows File Explorer to perform the unmapping.  Tried to unmap.  Whole computer froze and both monitors went black; I had to force power down.  Then I restarted computer and started perform unmap; Windows File Explorer hung again.  I rebooted and finally the mapped drive is gone and Windows File Explorer works again.  Perhaps someone with influence can get Microsoft to fix it; I can't believe I am the only person having the problem.

Comment: Hey Ken Smith, so sorry for the issues that you faced while mounting an azure file share. But as for the azure file share mounting, you should have checked the logs and network fiddler logs accordingly when you faced the system hang issue during Azure file share mounting. Though, its great that you eventually found another solution for your file shares.

Comment: I installed PowerShell 7 and this is what I get:

Comment: I installed PowerShell 7 and this is what I get:
The term 'Connect-AzRmAccount' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.  The specified module 'AzFilesHybrid' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
I have tried for several hours to get the script to work.

Comment: You will have to download the azure module for powershell and install it. Unless, you won't be able to run these cmdlets. Here is the command you have to run in powershell: - 'Install-Module -Name Az'. After this, run this command to install azfileshybrid module: - 'Import-Module -Name AzFilesHybrid -Force' and then try. It should be successful.

Comment: I ran install-Module -Name Az and it seemed to load several things.  Then I ran this:
PS C:\Users\Ken> import-module -Name AzFilesHybrid -Force
Import-Module: The specified module 'AzFilesHybrid' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
PS C:\Users\Ken>

Comment: Hi @Ken Smith, please refer the following link for importing the AzFilesHybrid module in powershell correctly. I was successfully able to do it. Link : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-enable#run-join-azstorageaccount.

Comment: KartikBhiwapurkar, I appreciate how hard you have worked to help me solve the problem.  You have patiently given me advice every step along the way.  I am not experienced with PowerShell, I don't have ActiveDirectory on Azure, and Azure pricing is so complicated that I don't know if I will incur expenses trying these additional steps.  I can't upvote and select the answer because the problem still persists and I would be misleading other members.  I think Microsoft should get a team of Azure and Windows 10 specialists and find out why File Explorer loops when mounting an Azure File share.

Answer (score 0):

•   You are mapping an azure file share to your Windows system and encountering the file explorer in hung state because there might be an antivirus/firewall software installed in your system that is blocking its access to the azure cloud after the mapping has been done. Also, syncing the data between the azure file share mapped and that in the cloud might not be possible as some Internet traffic filtering client/policy might be pushed/active on your system also that has disallowed the data access and sharing on port 445 that uses SMB over the Internet.

•   Also, the below powershell command will give you a verbose log of the connection to your Azure file share hosted in your storage account. Go through it to get some more information on what is happening in the background on your system.

```
  ‘ Connect-AzAccount -Environment "AzureCloud" #Adjust as-necessary
    $ResourceGroupName = "My-Resource-Group-Name"
    $StorageAccountName = "My-Sub-Name"
    Ipmo AzFilesBybrid
    Debug-AzStorageAccountAuth -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName - 
    ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Verbose ‘
```

Please find the below link for various troubleshooting methods to incorporate for the best-case description of your problem: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#unable-to-mount-azure-files-with-ad-credentials